# Add column in tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a common column in all tables in a database

For example:

I want to insert the column `TENANT_ID` in all tables in database

How can i do that.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can add it

if you have list of table in array

```
$column_name = 'TENANT_ID';
$size = '';
foreach($all_table_name as $each_table_name) {
   mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$each_table_name} ADD {$column_name} VARBINARY({$size})");
}
```

above code i just skilton you have to set accourding to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You use the ALTER TABLE SQL command as in:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

If you have multiple tables you'll need to apply this to each table in succession.

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp